# How To Know When A CS Cart Hook Fires?

Tags: hook, cs-cart

I need to confirm if I have selected the right hook from the hooks database. I need to auto order a vehicle on confirming an order. I chose the change_order_status and registered it in my init.php using

```
fn_register_hooks(
'change_order_status'
);
```

now in my func.php I have

```
if (!defined('AREA')) {die('Access denied');}

function fn_dellyman_change_order_status(&$status_to,&$status_from,&$order_info,&$force_notification,&$order_statuses,&$place_order) {
//Getting authentication data to identify user
$auth = $_SESSION['auth'];
var_dump($auth);
}
```

when I go to orders and switch the order from say open to complete, I expect to see the contents of auth rendered to the page at least as part of the request response. However I see no indication that the hook selected is the right one. How can i ensure the hook called is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
fn_set_notification('W','Description', var_export($varialble,true) );
```

this gives a notificcation after the hook fires and I found it very useful for my dev purposes.
The W can also be I and E for information and Error. Basically all it does is change the style of the popup

Answer (score 0):

depending on your CS-Cart version since 4.6.x is Tygh::$app['session']['auth'] but also depend if is done by AJAX request or normal place/edit order

On AJAX request you will not get any notification.

please try to use for a nicer notification:

```
fn_print_r(Tygh::$app['session']['auth']);
```